# Injecting audio track with a player to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, spotify

I was working with Spotify Web API and as a part of track retrieval response they provide url to 30 seconds track preview like this:

```
https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/c74432c268b6a5d0d7794e476023115b65e3105b?cid=b774e3bf851646c1b02928ea75802587
```

**(MUSIC WILL START PLAYING IF YOU OPEN URL)**

The browser detects that it's an audio file and displays the player.

**Is there a way to inject this player container to a div somehow?**

I tried the iframe, but it injects the whole window and I am only interested in the player component.

Comment: Simply inject the URL into the `<audio>` element's `src` attribute :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/c74432c268b6a5d0d7794e476023115b65e3105b?cid=b774e3bf851646c1b02928ea75802587" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
```